# What are the products of the thermal decomposition of potassium cyanate with carbon at elevated temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> What are the products of the thermal decomposition of potassium cyanate ($\ce{KOCN}$) with carbon ($\ce{C}$) at elevated temps ($\ce{300^\circ C - 1300^\circ C}$)?

I guess some of the nitrogen is lost and forms something. I'm trying to find out the full equation, but a google search brings up nothing concerning reduction of potassium cyanate with carbon.

Answer (score 3):

> [...] some of the nitrogen is lost and forms something [...]

Carbon is a good and cheap reductant, often used in the processing of oxidic ores - except when metal carbides are formed. Carbon dioxide a reasonable product in these reactions.

$\ce{2KOCN + C ->[\Delta] 2 KCN + CO2}$

Let's agree that potassium cyanate is reduced to potassium cyanide, while carbon dioxide is released.

Comment: wouldn't it be CO and not C02?

Comment: I found this: thermal decomposition of KCNO always causes some loss of nitrogen and leads to products that are somewhere from 1/4 to 1/3 K2CO3, the balance being KCN. So could the products be some K2C03 and also carbon monoxide?

Comment: You did not ask for the decomposition of $\ce{KOCN}$ in the first, but for its reaction with carbon at elevated temperature.